# Wavefront file conversion to WebGL array gone wrong somewhere

Tags: javascript, canvas, opengl-es, webgl

I'm making a WebGL graphics library and am having trouble creating the correct Array from an OBJ Wavefront (that is definitely correct). Looks like quite a simple bug to fix but can't find it. Wondering if someone might recongnize this type of bug.

[image: Teapot with wrong faces]

You can have a look at the live sample here:
http://robjte.de/webgl/8-3d.html

Here are the functions that I suspect are causing the issue.

```
function objectify (str) {
    var vertexRegex = /^v(?:\s(-?\d+.?(?:\d+)?))\s(-?\d+.?(?:\d+)?)\s(-?\d+.?(?:\d+)?)$/gim;
    var faceRegex = /^f\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)$/gim;
    var commentRegex = /^\s*\#.*$/gim;
    var emptyLineRegex = /^$/gim;

    var vertices = [];
    var faces = [];

    var m, i = 0;
    while (m = faceRegex.exec(str)) {
        faces.push([m[1], m[2], m[3]]);
        i++;
    }

    var m, i = 0;
    while (m = vertexRegex.exec(str)) {
        vertices.push([m[1], m[2], m[3]]);
        i++;
    }

    return {vertices: vertices, faces: faces};
}

function facesVerticesToWebGL (obj) {
    var f = obj.faces;
    var v = obj.vertices;

    var arr = [];
    f.forEach(function (val) {
        var vArr = v[parseInt(val) - 1];
        vArr.forEach(function (val2) {
            arr.push(parseFloat(val2));
        });
    });

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using a triple forEach block. My mistake was that `vArr` was an array and the parseInt was causing only the first value to be used so I was only drawing a third of the required vertices.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know what exactly is wrong with your code but here is a [very nicely commented](https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader/blob/master/webgl-obj-loader.js) version so maybe take a look at that and see where the differences are.